# How to have equal distance between the columns in a table

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS. I have created a table where the distance between first and the second column is correct where as the distance between second and third column and the distance between third and forth column is greater than the first one. I want the distance between the second and third column and the distance between the third and forth column  should be same as that of first and second column. How can I reduce this distance.
**HTML**

```
<table class="img_table">
<tr>
<td>
<img src="./images/FACILITIES.PNG"/>
<p><center>FACILITIES</br>MANAGEMENT</center></p>
</td>
<td>
<img src="./images/RESALE.PNG"/>
<p><center>RESALE</br>& RENTALS</center></p>
</td>
<td>
<img src="./images/AIR_CONDITIONER.PNG"/>
<p><center>AIR CONDITIONER</br>SERVICES</center></p>
</td>
<td>
<img src="./images/DEEP_CLEANING.PNG"/>
<p><center>DEEP CLEANING</br>& JANITORSERVICES</center></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<img src="./images/INTERIOR.PNG"/>
<p><center>INTERIOR</br>WORK</center></p>
</td>
<td>
<img src="./images/PAINTING.PNG"/>
<p><center>PAINTING</br>WORK</center></p>
</td>
<td>
<img src="./images/LANDSCAPING.PNG"/>
<p><center>LANDSCAPING</br>WORK</center></p>
</td>
<td>
<img src="./images/PEST_CONTROL.PNG"/>
<p><center>PEST CONTROL</br>WORK</center></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<img src="./images/SECURITY.PNG"/>
<p><center>SECURITY</br>SERVICES</center></p>
</td>
<td>
<img src="./images/CONCIERGE.PNG"/>
<p><center>CONCEIRGE</br>SERVICES</center></p>
</td>
<td>
<img src="./images/MOBILE_LANDLINE.PNG"/>
<p><center>MOBILE/LANDLINE</br>CONNECTION</center></p>
</td>

<td>
<img src="./images/UTILITY.PNG"/>
<p><center>UTILITY &</br>BILL PAYMENT</center></p>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table.img_table{
position: absolute;
left:160px;
top: 295px; 
display: inline;
font-size:10px;
font-family:Verdana;
}

table.img_table td {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px
}
table.img_table td img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px
    height: 81px;
    width: 80px;
}
```

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ABBx/) out of it

Comment: That's because the text `AIR CONDITIONER SERVICES` and `DEEP CLEANING
& JANITOR SERVICES` is pushing it out.

Comment: @LeeTaylor Yes I know that. But what can be done make equidistant

Comment: Either split the text onto more lines, make the font size smaller, or make each column a specific width that allows for your text as it stands

Comment: @LeeTaylor How can I make the third option, can you show me in fiddle

Comment: As others have pointed out, tables do have their uses but this isn't possibly the best way to use them. Here's a solution anyway, http://jsfiddle.net/6ABBx/3/

Answer (score 0):

Tables are designed to resize to fit the content, so having longer words or wider images will mean larger columns (I think), this can be fixed by inputting "white space" into the smaller columns or removing text from the larger ones.  I am sure there is another way to do it, but it would have to involve resizing the text in some way.  Hope this helps :)

Comment: I just realised it could also be done by giving each column on the table its own id or class and resizing it with width: ...

Answer (score 0):

Well this all is happening because of Your long names written on your table if you write only one letter each then you will get your coding is right just the problem is of the length of the words.

To prevent this you can do this :

---

```
table.img_table{
position: absolute;
left:160px;
top: 295px; 
display: inline;
font-size:10px;
font-family:Verdana;
}

    table.img_table td {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px
}
    table.img_table td img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px
    height: 81px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

---

By simply increasing the `width: 100px` and it will obviously give you equal distance between all your images.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sR8j2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add following CSS.

```
table.img_table td {
    vertical-align: top;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you paragraph tag is not sized while image has size. so you must add

```
tr{
vertical-align:top;
}
p{
width:80px;
}
```

and remove all those **br** and **center** tags. i rather like to use divs instead of table 
http://jsfiddle.net/6ABBx/4/